# CSS translate not working fully on Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have an element on my app that slides into view when I click a button and then slides out of view when I click the button again. I am doing this with a combination of CSS and JS, it is working fine on Chrome and Firefox but it works only in part in Safari.

In Safari it doesn't slides in but just appears abruptly but then it does slides out fine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ewLdm75n/20/

Here is the CSS:

```
#testModes {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

#testModes.testModes-active {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
     transform: translateY(0);
}
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.testModesToggle', function() {
    var state = $('#testModes').attr('class');

    if (state === 'testModes-active') {
        $('#testModes').removeClass('testModes-active').delay(100).fadeToggle();
    } else {
        $('#testModes').fadeToggle(0).addClass('testModes-active');
    }

});
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle with this please?

Comment: Sure, I added it to the OP, here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/ewLdm75n/20/

Comment: Why do you use 0 in `fadeToggle(0)` instead of just `toggle()`?

Comment: Because toggle() makes it slide in an abrupt manner as opposed to fadeToggle(0) wich allows the css transform to take place. The 0 also prevents it from fading in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a fix for it. Just changed fadeToggle(0) to slideDown(0)and it solved the problem. I am not entire sure as to why, but it works! Here is the code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.testModesToggle', function() {
    var state = $('#testModes').attr('class');

    if (state === 'testModes-active') {
        $('#testModes').removeClass('testModes-active').delay(100).fadeToggle();
    } else {
        $('#testModes').slideDown(0).addClass('testModes-active');
    }

});
```